# How do i check user authentication on application level Django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views

How do check the user is authenticated or not when some one try to access a page through url.
ex: http://127.0.0.1/test 
when some one types the url i want to check in the page that url redirects, that user is authenticated or not.?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it inside view, you can check `request.user.is_authenticated()`. In some methods of Class-based views, this is not provided as parameter, so you can access it using `self.request`.

If you're trying to do it inside template:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    You're authenticated!
{% else %}
    You're not authenticated :(
{% endif %}
```

but request must be passed into context, by context processor or by hand, inside your view function.

Comment: On every template i need to place this piece of code? Is there any APP level setting we can do?

Comment: It depends on your use of that code. If you're trying to restrict user from accessing whole page, you should do it inside view or consider use of [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator. If you're trying to hide some global content, consider using one base template and extending from it.